# How do I prevent Visual Studio Code from accessing and showing global python installations on my system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have 2 global python installations and 2 python venv.
[image]

I don't use global interpreters and don't want vscode to show these 2.

Is there a way to stop vscode from accessing these global python interpreters and showing them?

I had manually added the python interpreter paths for venvs and I am using that and not the global interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

Python extension retrieves your environment variables to provide you with the choice of python interpreter.

Unless you delete the python path in the environment variable, it will always be displayed, (but this is **not recommended**).

Answer (score 0):

Try opening VSCode as administrator. Right click VSCode and select 'Run as administrator'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).